# ¿Cómo almacenar varios nombres en una variable en Java?

Tags: java

¡Hola! Estoy realizando un ejercicio lo cuál me está pidiendo saber quién ha conseguir la mayor distancia, por esa parte lo tengo entendido, pero también me están pidiendo que ingrese un nombre con su distancia.

He visto que se puede utilizar un array, pero tengo entendido que recorre de 0... al número que le indique o en qué manera puedo utilizarlo y que se vincule con su distancia.

Agradecería su apoyo, muchas gracias.

Mi código:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int n;
    double distancia, mayor;
   
    System.out.println("Saber el ganador de la competencia");
    System.out.println("Ingresar la distancia en centimetros");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------");

    do {
        System.out.print("Introduce numero de participantes: ");
        n = sc.nextInt();  //n contiene el número de participantes
    } while (n <= 0); //repetir mientras que el valor de n sea <= 0

    System.out.print("Distancia del participante 1: ");
    distancia = sc.nextDouble(); //distancia del primer participante

    mayor = distancia; //mayor distancia alcanzada
   
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {  // el resto de distancias desde el participante 2 hasta el participante n         
        System.out.print("Distancia del participante " + i + ": ");
        distancia = sc.nextDouble();
        if (distancia > mayor){  // se compara la nota con la mayor y con la menor actual
            mayor = distancia;
        }
    }

    // mostrar resultados
    System.out.println("La mayor distancia alcanzada " + mayor);
    }
```

Comment: Puedes hacerlo creando objetos donde guardes el nombre de la persona y su distancia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En efecto, si quieres guardar varios nombres en una misma variable, lo que quieres guardar es **una lista de nombres**, es decir, un Array de Strings donde almacenar los nombres, te he cambiado ligeramente el código, ya que he visto que al primer participante lo sacas del for para introducir las distancias, simplemente para asignar al mayor la distancia de ese participante.

No es una buena práctica sacar un caso de un for cuando el comportamiento va a ser exactamente el mismo, lo que he hecho es que por defecto la mayor distancia siempre va a ser 0, a nada que recorran un poco de distancia la condición `if (distancia > mayor)` se va a cumplir, y el mayor se va actualizar. Tienes el código comentado con la nueva funcionalidad, si tienes alguna duda o necesitas alguna aclaración, no dudes en ponerlo en un comentario y lo añado a la respuesta.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int n;
    double distancia;
    double mayor = 0;
    System.out.println("Saber el ganador de la competencia");
    System.out.println("Ingresar la distancia en centimetros");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------");

    do {
        System.out.print("Introduce numero de participantes: ");
        n = sc.nextInt();  //n contiene el número de participantes
    } while (n <= 0); //repetir mientras que el valor de n sea <= 0
    
    //Declaramos un Array del tamaño al número de participantes
    String[] nombres = new String [n];
    //Declaramos un indice para el array de nombres de participantes
    int posicionParticipante = 0;
    
    //Declaramos un indice para el ganador del array de nombres de participantes
    int posicionGanador = 0;
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {  // el resto de distancias desde el participante 2 hasta el participante n         
        System.out.print("Distancia del participante " + i + ": ");
        distancia = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Nombre del participante " + i + ": ");
        //Lo introducimos en el array
        nombres[posicionParticipante] = sc.next();       
        
        if (distancia > mayor){  // se compara la nota con la mayor y con la menor actual
            mayor = distancia;
            posicionGanador = posicionParticipante;
        }
        //Incrementamos el índice
        posicionParticipante++;
    }
    // mostrar resultados
    System.out.println("La mayor distancia alcanzada " + mayor);
    // Mostramos el nombre del ganador
    System.out.println("Participante ganador " + nombres[posicionGanador]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Creamos una clase para instanciar objetos en los cuales vamos a almacenar el nombre y la distancia

```
 public class Participante{
    
     private String Nombre;
     private double Distancia;

    public Participante(String Nombre,double Distancia){
       this.Nombre = Nombre;
       this.Distancia = Distancia;
    }

    public string GetNombre(){ 
       return this.Nombre;
    }

    public double GetDistancia(){ 
       return this.Distancia;
    }

    public void SetDistancia(double Distancia){ 
       this.Distancia = Distancia;
    }
   

    public void SetNombre(String Nombre){ 
       this.Nombre = Nombre;
    }
}
```

Ahora para crear participantes y mostrar los datos de estos mismos, usamos el constructor y los metodos Get

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

int n;

Participante mayor;

System.out.println("Saber el ganador de la competencia");
System.out.println("Ingresar la distancia en centimetros");
System.out.println("--------------------------------------");

do {
    System.out.print("Introduce numero de participantes: ");
    n = sc.nextInt();  //n contiene el número de participantes
} while (n <= 0); //repetir mientras que el valor de n sea <= 0

System.out.print("Distancia del participante 1: ");
double distancia = sc.nextDouble(); //distancia del primer participante
System.out.print("Nombre del participante 1:");
String nombre = sc.nextLine();

//Instanciamos un objeto de tipo participante 
mayor = new Participante(nombre,distancia);

for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {  // el resto de distancias desde el participante 2 hasta el participante n         
    System.out.print("Distancia del participante " + i + ": ");
    distancia = sc.nextDouble();
    if (distancia > mayor.GetDistancia()){  // se compara la nota con la mayor y con la menor actual
System.out.print("Nombre del participante 1:");
String nombre = sc.nextLine();
        mayor = new Participante(nombre,distancia);
    }
}

// mostrar resultados
System.out.println("La mayor distancia alcanzada " + mayor.GetDistancia() + "Nombre del participante "+ mayor.GetNombre());
}
```